# Swapping buttons in a grid - tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

This is my first day of tkinter and I need help to understand how to code some basic functions, please.

What I am doing is like a puzzle game, I have made a grid with buttons and on each button there is a picture (one button is one piece of my puzzle). I would like to make a function that help me to swap my pieces when I click on two of them. But I don't really know how to proceed.

So for example I took the following image https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/786375.jpg, I have cut this one in four parts and converted these four images into numpy arrays and finally put them in a list `l`. So `l = [im1,im2,im3,im4]`.

And then with tkinter with the following code I made my grid as you can see below:

```
from tkinter import *
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

window = Tk()


l_img = [ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=Image.fromarray(l[i]),master = window) for i in range(len(l))]

Button(window, borderwidth=1,image = l_img[0]).grid(row=0, column=0)
Button(window, borderwidth=1,image = l_img[1]).grid(row=0, column=1)
Button(window, borderwidth=1,image = l_img[2]).grid(row=1, column=0)
Button(window, borderwidth=1,image = l_img[3]).grid(row=1, column=1)

window.mainloop()
```

[image]

I would love to swap two pieces of such kind of puzzle when clicking on the tiles, could someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a list to store the selected buttons.  If two buttons are selected, get the grid information using `grid_info()` and swap the two selected buttons using the grid information:

```py
from tkinter import *
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

window = Tk()

l = [(255*np.random.rand(250,250)).astype(np.uint8) for i in range(4)]
l_img = [ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=Image.fromarray(l[i]),master = window) for i in range(len(l))]

def click(btn):
    selected.append(btn)
    if len(selected) == 2:
        # get grid information of the selected buttons
        info1 = selected[0].grid_info()
        info2 = selected[1].grid_info()
        # swap the buttons
        selected[0].grid(row=info2['row'], column=info2['column'])
        selected[1].grid(row=info1['row'], column=info1['column'])
        # clear selection
        selected.clear()

selected = []
font=("Arial 64 bold")
for i in range(len(l)):
    btn = Button(window, borderwidth=1, image=l_img[i], text=i+1, font=font, compound="c")
    btn.config(command=lambda b=btn: click(b))
    btn.grid(row=i//2, column=i%2)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Wow, that was quick! Thank you again for your answer, it is really helpful and it works really well.